# Twilio Node v12 upgrade issues

Tags: api, twilio

We have had Salesforce-Twilio integration running in Production for over a year. We send text messages to our customers with both Apex and ProcessBuilder logic, all the necessary Connected App and Permisson sets have been in place for the Twilio Message Service and a function on the Twilio side. A new Twilio upgrade requires that this Twilio function be re-deployed with Node v12 and Twilio has provided documentation to do this. I have tried everything I can think of and can't get past error msgs such as 82002-Error on Function Response and an authentication error 82005-Error getting token, blah, blah. I have tried with several sets of credentials that I know are good, plus dbl and triple-checked the steps, and nothing is working. Is their Salesforce integration buggy ? Can anyone report having any success in making this upgrade ?

Comment: You'll have to check with Twilio support.

Comment: Resolved-updating to perhaps help others. I opened a case with Twilio support and even though they did not pinpoint the issue, the dialog at least helped me to figure out where I went wrong. The Twilio documentation is awful and a YouTube vid out there is worse.

The docs read as if the function that needs the v12 upgrade will be configured with a 'Message Container', implying this is different from the original 'Message Service'. My perception that the Message Service could be removed was wrong. Once I recreated it and configured with the new function's url, I was able to have success.